# How to repair installation, accidentally deleted /sbin/initctl

Tags: data-recovery, upstart

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a VirtualBox. I was trying to create a central log server with rsyslog. At some point I made changes to the conf file and tried to restart rsyslog, but started getting the following error:

Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Following what this question suggested 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997229

I issued the following commands

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

However this did not resolve the issue as running the following was not actually restarting rsyslog.

`service rsyslog restart`

So I tried to undo the initial commands by doing

```
dpkg-divert --local --remove /sbin/initctl
rm /sbin/initctl
```

However deleting initctl started causing other issues. So I rebooted the machine, and the machine wouldn't boot normally. I went into recovery mode, and before displaying the recovery menu it printed `/proc/self/fd/9: 5: /proc/self/fd/9: initctl: not found`.

Does anyone know how I can restore the initctl?

Edit: I also booted the VM with the iso image for 12.04 and went to recovery menu, however there does not seem to be a way of restoring the deleted files.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-installing Upstart:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install upstart
```

There is no way to recover lost binary otherwise. `initctl` unlike `start`, `stop` or `restart` is a separate executable and not a link to init itself.

If you do not have connectivity, see which version of Upstart package you have `dpkg -l|grep upstart` and download the package manually on another machine to a USB stick and reinstall from the stick. All dependencies are correct since you're just reinstalling the exact same version.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem and this is how I did it and my ubuntu 14.04 started booting normal.

1. get a live CD/USB, boot it and choose try ubuntu without installing.
2. CTRL+ALT+T to get to the terminal
3. copy the */sbin/initctl* file from the live CD/USB to the */sbin* of the installed ubuntu on the machine.
4. sudo cp /sbin/initctl /media/ubuntu/*your ubuntu partition*/sbin

**Note:** replace "your ubuntu partition" with the partition where you have your original ubuntu installed.