# initctl: event failed after "login: *Starting CPU ..."

Tags: 14.04, boot, 64-bit

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I recall the last thing i tried doing in terminal was to attempt removing packettracer which failed to start on my system. I followed the guide found in
[How to uninstall PacketTracer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674222/how-to-uninstall-packettracer)
 Sad thing is, after this the OS started freezing up and so I decided to reboot and all hell broke loose. The normal boot would get stuck with the blinker at the top left corner of the screen (not blinking). I tried booting with Advaned options and chose recovery mode. That's when it reported

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS nana-qhuacy-HP-Stream tty1
nana-qhuacy-HP-Stream login:  *Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon    [OK]
initctl: Event failed
_
```

I've tried both answers in 
[How to repair installation, accidentally deleted /sbin/initctl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307007/how-to-repair-installation-accidentally-deleted-sbin-initctl)
The second answer came close to working but also reported an error.

Answer (score 1):

[Similar errors](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ubuntu-12-04-wont-boot-initctl-event-failed-4175444899-print/) were apparently caused by accidental removals.
Try getting the log of apt-get, using any of the methods outlined below the line (or otherwise)

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep Remove
```

Look for unintentional removals. Even if you knew which ones were removed, past stories indicate mixed results. Lots of accidental remavals in Ubuntu end up costing a reinstall. It does seem similar to DM issues though. 
In which case

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

should do.

---

I don't think it's an issue with `initctl` itself. We need more information; logs would help. Means and directions which can give hints to the problem follow.

Does `Ctrl+Alt+F2` or similar work? It gives you full shell access, it means most of your OS is working.

Are your other OSes working normally? Easy way to tell if it's a hardware issue (temporary one?).

Looking at logs and command history (using a live CD, another OS or mounting your installed partition elsewhere) might help shed some light on what exactly went wrong.
For example, the system could've gotten messed up irrespective of your actions(unlikely), or something else you did which becomes effective after a reboot.

Some of the packages you removed in https://askubuntu.com/a/674294/600169 could be installed previously, and just reinstalled when trying to install PacketTracer (definetely unlikely to cause the initctl error). Also, you could double-check if you've removed other packages along with the purge.